# How to know if an IP address is in local network, xcode

Tags: ios, ip-address, ping

I want to know whether an IP address is in Local network or not using my objective-c(Xcode) program. But, problem is that for every IP address (even if it is not in network), the result is success. Here is the code and please help me how to find if an IP address is in local network correctly.

```
            bool success = false;
            const char *host_name = [@"192.168.0.115" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL,
                                                                                        host_name);
            SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
            success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
            bool isAvailable = success && (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) &&
            !(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);
            if (isAvailable)
            {
              //success
              //connect to IP address                      

            }
            else
            {
               //Not success
            }
```

Comment: this is not really a ping. A ping means sending a ICMP packet to target IP and get replies from it

Comment: But,I have to write the code in Xcode only.Please any one reply if you know the answer

Comment: @sushma did u find the solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
Reachability* reachability = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain]; // does not work with local IP, ARC is not used.
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

`netStatus` will give you the status.

**UPDATE**

`Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:` does not work with local IP, as it cannot resolve the address. Therefore, this solution does NOT answer the question. However, as quoted from @Kerberos in the comment below, this [ARC-enabled library](https://github.com/ebley/reachabilityWithAddressPing) can be used to check the connectivity with local IP address.

Comment: For this code,I am getting not reachable for every IP address even if it is in the local Network.

Comment: So, is your device really accessible to the IP ?

Comment: Obviously, reachabilityWithHostName accept a stringType of the HostName, not of the ip address.
To ping the ip address you must use reachabilityWithAddress that accept a const struct sockaddr_in type.

Comment: @Kerberos not true. Network API will resolve IP. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12178517/188331

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Have you ever tried that code? I do and it doesn't work with the local ipv4. If you have a case that works, I will be happy to correct the answer.
I solved the problem using a ping to the ip, [this](https://github.com/ebley/reachabilityWithAddressPing) is a working example of the use of reachability for check the connection with the use of 'reachabilityWithAddress' and next there is a simple ping to check a local ip.

Comment: You maybe right. Local IP cannot be resolved by Network API, as quoted from other answers. Therefore this answer is invalid.